# xmlの名前空間をhttpsにしてはいけない？

Tags: xml

サイト内をhttps対応にしています

その中の名前空間もhttpsに対応しないといけないのかなと思い質問しました

例えば、exif内のexif.jsにある
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
もhttpsの方がいいのかなと思いましたが

会社の別の人に
名前空間だし、リクエストしていないからhttpのままじゃないといけないよということでした

逆にこの名前空間をhttpをhttpsに変えてしまうと、他のところがhttpだった場合に一緒ではないので問題になりますか？

→
結局答えていただいたようにhttpのままで変えないようにしました
ありがとうございました(20230505)
お礼はどうすれば・・・

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 名前空間もhttpsは対応しないといけないのかなと

ウェブとは関係のない仕組みなので、https 対応は不要です。名前空間なので、勝手に変更したら対応ソフトが動かなくなると思います。

Comment: 恐れ入ります、勉強になります

Comment: httpのままで変えないようにしました、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 10):

名前空間に関する仕様を探してみました。

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NSNameComparison

> The two URIs are treated as strings, and they are identical if and only if the strings are identical, that is, if they are the same sequence of characters.
> (2 つの URI は文字列として扱われ、文字列が同一である場合 (つまり、同じ文字シーケンスである場合) にのみ同一です。)

名前空間として与えられた URI はエスケープの処理やパスの正規化などはされず、文字列そのままのものとして比較されることになっています。

また、

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, should have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists).
> (名前空間名は、その意図された目的を果たすために、一意性と持続性の特性を持つ必要があります。 スキーマ (存在する場合) の取得に直接使用できるようにすることは目標ではありません。)

とあり、同じ意味の名前空間ならば同じ文字の並びが維持されることが期待されます。

名前空間としての URI はスキーマやドキュメントを提供する URL というわけではなくただ区別するための名前ですので、サービスを提供するサイトの URL と関係ありません。

特別な理由があってスキーマもアプリケーションも全てが新しい名前空間に変更するということであればそれが悪いとは言い切れませんが、この場合は画像フォーマットの規格で与えられている名前空間なので変更すると破綻してしまいます。 変更してはいけません。

Comment: おおお、勉強になります、ありがとうございます

Comment: そうですか丁寧にありがとうございますhttpのままでかえないようにしました、他の人はかえていたのでそこも元に戻しました